# Alternative methods to configure the "host" variable in nuxt-schema-org?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

Building an app in Nuxt3. Using [Unhead's Schema.org module](https://unhead-schema-org.harlanzw.com/integrations/nuxt/module).

The module appears to require a "canonical host" in order to function. This config variable is assigned in the nuxt.config file (step 2 on the doc).

The issue is, my host needs to be variable. An instance of the app can be deployed on any domain.

Upon initialization, I'm capturing the domain using Nuxt's `useRequestURL()` composable, then storing it in a Pinia store. But neither of these methods seem accessible in nuxt.config.

Is there a way to access this module's config outside of the nuxt.config file?

I don't think environment variables will cut it here, since I cannot define different ones based on the domain being deployed to (via Cloudflare Pages).